# Enviando email com nodemailer

Tags: angularjs, node.js, nodemailer

Estou fazendo uma aplicação com `angularjs` e tenho um form de contato com nome, email, telefone e mensagem.

Preciso que o conteúdo deste form vá para o email do cliente e estou tentando utilizar o *nodemailer* mas estou com dúvidas.

Criei uma estrutura da seguinte forma:

```
root:
    ├─index.html
    └─ _js
       └─ script.js
```

Dentro do `script.js` coloquei o código abaixo:

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var transportador = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: 'gmail',
      auth: {
        user: 'sbeckerassessoria@gmail.com',
        pass: 'futebol11'
        }
    });

exports.send = function(){

    var configuracoes = {
        from: 'Seu Nome <sbeckerassessoria@gmail.com>',
        to: 'Nome do Destinatário <emaildodestinatario@gmail.com>, Outra Pessoa <stromdh@gmail.com>',
        subject: 'Assunto do Email',
        text: 'Conteúdo do email em texto',
        html: '<h1>Conteúdo do email em HTML</h1>'
    };

    transportador.sendMail(configuracoes, function(error, info) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log('Email enviado ' + info.response);
        }
    });
}
```

Não sei como chamar o arquivo de envio a partir do submit ou de um evento no botão.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score -2):

Acredito que você terá que inserir o script dentro de um Controller da página `index.html`.
Adicione a função de enviar e-mail ao scopo do controller.

Exemplo:

```
$scope.sendMail = function {    

    transportador.sendMail(configuracoes, function(error, info) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log('Email enviado ' + info.response);
        }
    });
 }
```

na `index.html` insira no botão: `ng-click=sendMail()`

Answer (score -2):

Eu uso a biblioteca `nodemailer-smtp-transport` junto com a lib `nodemailer`. O script de envio que uso em meus projetos é esse aqui:

```
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer"),
     smtpTransport = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport');


const smtpConfig = smtpTransport({
    host: "smtp.seuhost.com",
    port: 587,
    ignoreTLS: true,
    secure : true,
    tls: {
        rejectUnauthorized: true
    },
    auth: {
        user: "Seu login",
        pass: "sua senha"
    }
});

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpConfig);

const message  = {
    from: "Seu Nome ",
    to: "Nome do Destinatário ",
    subject: "Assunto do Email",
    text: "Conteúdo do email em texto",
    html: "<h1>Conteúdo do email em HTML</h1>",
    headers: {
        'X-Laziness-level': 1000
    }
};


transporter.sendMail(message, function(error, info) {               
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log('Email enviado ' + info.response);
    }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Utilizo o nodemailer com o react, a estrutura se mantém a mesma.
No react faço o seguinte:

No form chamo uma função de envio que constumo chamar de `handleSubmit()`, dentro dessa função é setada os dados que serão enviados via e-mail. Utilizo o adonis para transpor estes dados pelo express.

Basicamente, para efetivar o envio do e-mail, vc precisa da função do nodemailer que é o `transport.sendMail(jsonDaMensagem, function (capturaDeErro, informacaoErro)`

Basicamente, você precisa conseguir mandar os dados para seu arquivo e armazená-los em alguma variável. Neste caso, se você recebe de alguma outra requisição, é necessário recebê-las e utilizá-las no corpo do e-mail, dentro do json `message`.

No express você pode receber uma rota como:

```
app.post('/enviarEmail', (req, res) => {
  const {
   userEmail,
   outraPessoa
  } = request.body;

  transportador.sendMail (configuracoes, (erro, info) {
   ...
  }

});
```

Nas configurações do nodemailer, você vai poder acessar essas variáveis se estiver configuradas no mesmo script, quando chamada a rota acima é importante que seja disparado o transportador.sendMail, isso porque esta rota quem está recebendo os dados e já faz a função de efetivar o envio de e-mail.

```
var configuracoes = {
    from: 'Seu Nome <sbeckerassessoria@gmail.com>',
    to: 'Nome do Destinatário <${userEmail}>, Outra Pessoa <${outraPessoa}>',
    subject: 'Assunto do Email',
    text: 'Conteúdo do email em texto',
    html: '<h1>Conteúdo do email em HTML</h1>'
};
```

Quando a função for chamada então, o transportador.sendMail, irá encaminhar seu e-mail com as novas configurações que foram recebidas por requisição do seu formulário. Não sei se no angular segue este modelo, mas no react constumo utilizar desta maneira utilizando o adonis para fazer a requisição para o express.

Answer (score -4):

> Solução de envio de e-mail usando node.
> É basicamente uma api que recebe os dados e envia um e-mail.
> lembre-se de criar uma conta válida, para este exemplo uso uma criada no Outlook.com
> Como cliente de teste, usei o postman.

app.js

```
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';

import { z } from "zod"; //para validar se o cliente tá mandando os campos

import nodemailer from "nodemailer";

const app = express();

const jsonParser = bodyParser.json();

const PORT = 3333;

app.post("/send-email", jsonParser, async (req, res) => {

  const createEmailBodySchema = z.object({
    to: z.string(),
    subject: z.string(),
    text: z.string(),
    html: z.string(),
  });

  const validateBody = createEmailBodySchema.safeParse(req.body);

  const { to, subject, text, html } = req.body;

  if (validateBody.success) {
    const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: "smtp-mail.outlook.com",
      port: 587,
      auth: {
        user: "seuEmail@outlook.com.br",
        pass: "123456",
      },
    });

    const message = {
      from: "seuEmail@outlook.com.br",
      to,
      subject,
      text,
      html,
    };

    transport.sendMail(message, (err) => {
      if (err)
        return res.status(400).send({
          version: "1.0.0",
          statusCode: 400,
          message: "Erro: E-mail não pode ser enviado.",
        });

      return res.status(200).send({
        version: "1.0.0",
        statusCode: 200,
        message: "E-mail enviado com sucesso.",
      });
    });
  } else {return res.status(400).send({
      version: "1.0.0",
      statusCode: 400,
      message: [],
      error: [{ error: "bad request, parâmetro inválido ou ausente." }],
    });
  }
});


app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Http Server Running in port :${PORT}`);
});
```

> Package.json

```
{
  "name": "nodemailer",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "server e-mail with node",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "app.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node src/app.js"
  },
  "author": "Alexandre Jr",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "nodemailer": "^6.9.3",
    "zod": "^3.21.4"
  }
}
```

> requisição do postman:

```
Headers: Content-Type = application/json
Body: {
    "to": "email@destino.com",
    "subject": "Solicitação de recuperação de senha do App",
    "text": "Recuperação de senha \nTrata-se da sua solicitação de recuperação de senha.",
    "html": "<h1><strong>Recuperação de senha</strong></h1><p>Solicitação de recuperação de senha do App.</p>"
}
```